# Exception: attempt to insert section 0 but there are only 0 sections after the update

Tags: swift, uitableview

I've got a UITableView showing Chat Messages as ViewCells.

I'm holding chat messages in `var groupedMessages = [Date : [ChatMessage]]()`.

I'm using the keys of `groupedMessages` as table sections.

Below is a code snippet from my sendChatMessage function.

- The `if` section handles cases where I'm starting a brand new
  conversation.
- The `else` section appends the message at the bottom of
  the TableView.

The `else` part works just fine. 
But the App crashes in the `if` section with error `attempt to insert section 0 but there are only 0 sections after the update`.

There are several solutions posted on stackoverflow and I believe I've done everything that's mentioned and referenced in there but can't get it to work.
Can anyone see where my mistake is?

MANY THANKS FOR YOUR HELP !!!

```swift
...
if (self.groupedMessages.count == 0) {
    let tsp = newMessage.tsp
    let message: [ChatMessage] = [newMessage]
    self.groupedMessages = [tsp! : message]
    self.MessageList.insertSections(IndexSet(integer: 0), with: .none)
    let path = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    self.MessageList.insertRows(at: [path], with: .fade)
    self.MessageTextField.text = nil
    self.MessageList.scrollToRow(at: path, at: .top, animated: false)
    self.SendMessageButton.loadingIndicator(false)
} else {
    self.groupedMessages[self.keys.last!]?.append(newMessage)
    let path = IndexPath(row: self.groupedMessages[self.keys.last!]!.count-1, section: self.keys.count-1)
    self.MessageList.insertRows(at: [path], with: .fade)
    self.MessageTextField.text = nil
    self.MessageList.scrollToRow(at: path, at: .bottom, animated: true)
    self.SendMessageButton.loadingIndicator(false)
}
...
```

Here are my implementations for `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection`

```swift
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.keys.count
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.groupedMessages[keys[section]]!.count
    }
```

Comment: I highly recommend to use an array of custom  `Section` objects rather than a `key` array and dictionaries. It's much easier to maintain.

Comment: @vadian - ok, thanks for the hint!!! But concerning my more immediate problem: can you spot my error?

Comment: @vadian: Do you know what the problem could be here? Many thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `insertRows` after inserting the section. After `insertSection` the table will call `numberOfRowsInSection`, and since you've updated your model (`groupedMessages`), all will be well. If you need to subsequently scroll or do other things, could you wrap the insertSection in a `performBatchUpdates:completion:` call.

I also suspect your `numberOfSections` method is wrong... but that depends on what `self.keys` is. What is self.keys? You don't appear to be updating it in this code.

Comment: I've edited my question to also show my implementations for `numberOfSections ` and `numberOfRowsInSection `. With regards to reloading the table: It was my understanding that `insertRows` is calling the relevant delegate and data source methods for me - at least it seams to do so in the `else` part of my code that executes clean and with the expected results.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm now only setting `self.groupedMessages = [tsp! : message]` and then immediately after `self.MessageList.insertSections(IndexSet(integer: 0), with: .none)` but still getting `Thread 1: Exception: "attempt to insert section 0 but there are only 0 sections after the update"`